# returning list from dolist loop, instead return NIL

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Can you help me with my code, I don't see why it's not returning my wireList, it's just returning NIL

```
(defun table-wires-position(inputTable inputPosition)
   (let ((wireList () ))
     (dolist (x (table-wires inputTable) wireList)
        (if (or (equal-position-p (wire-OriginCoin x) inputPosition) 
                (equal-position-p (wire-destinCoin x) inputPosition))
                   (cons x wireList)))))
```

Answer (score 7):

First, note that you are technically correct ([the best kind of correct](http://theinfosphere.org/Number_1.0#Quotes)) in writing code like this:

```
(let ((wireList ()))
  (dolist (x (table-wires inputTable) wireList)
    …)
```

This does mean that `dolist` is returning `wireList`.  The question title, “returning list from dolist loop, instead return NIL” is a bit misleading then, because: (i) `nil` *is* a list, so you're returning a list; (ii) you *are* returning `wireList`. The problem is that you haven't actually modified `wireList` during the execution of the `dolist`.  The function `cons` simply *returns* a new cons cell; it doesn't modify places, so you're not modifying `wireList`.  You can use `push`, instead, as the following code does.  Since you're using an `if` with no *else* part, you can use `when`.

```
(defun table-wires-position(inputTable inputPosition)
  (let ((wireList ()))
    (dolist (x (table-wires inputTable) wireList)
      (when (or (equal-position-p (wire-OriginCoin x) inputPosition) 
                (equal-position-p (wire-destinCoin x) inputPosition))
        (push x wireList))))) ; or (setf wireList (cons x wireList))
```

On a stylistic node, I often use [`&aux` variables](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_da.htm) for these kind of result variables;  it avoids a level of nesting:

```
(defun table-wires-position (inputTable inputPosition &aux (wireList '()))
  (dolist (x (table-wires inputTable) wireList)
    (when (or (equal-position-p (wire-OriginCoin x) inputPosition) 
              (equal-position-p (wire-destinCoin x) inputPosition))
      (push x wireList))))
```

Note that by `push`ing elements into the list, you're getting them in reverse order from `inputTable`.  You could get them in the same order by returning `(nreverse wireList)` instead, if you wanted.  Even better, since you're really just returning an list with certain elements removed, you might as well just use [`remove-if-not`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm):

```
(defun table-wires-position (inputTable inputPosition)
  (remove-if-not #'(lambda (x) 
                     (or (equal-position-p (wire-OriginCoin x) inputPosition) 
                         (equal-position-p (wire-destinCoin x) inputPosition)))
                 inputTable))
```

Comment: @Baggers Oops!  Good catch.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Joshua's answer is the way to go here, but as an addendum this is the version using the loop macro.

```
(defun table-wires-position (input-table input-position)
  (loop :for x :in input-table 
     :if (or (equal-position-p (wire-origin-coin x) input-position) 
             (equal-position-p (wire-destin-coin x) input-position))
     :collect x))
```

Also dont use camelcase names as symbols are case-insensitive so the following are all **the same**

```
inputPosition INputPosition INPUTPOSITION iNpUtPoSiTiOn
```

Always use hypens e.g. input-position

Comment: Nitpick: the reader (by default) upcases everything so when it encounters `inputPosition` `INputPosition` `INPUTPOSITION` `iNpUtPoSiTiOn`, it upcases the strings and interns them, so you get the same symbol.  After `(setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :preserve)` you'd get four distinct symbols.  See [23.1.2.1 Examples of Effect of Readtable Case on the Lisp Reader](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/23_aba.htm) for more information.  The `:invert` case is handy if you're working with camel case, because `defun` is still `'DEFUN`, but `ZwCreateFile` is `'|ZwCreateFile|`.

Answer (score 1):

Small addition:

If a macro starts with `do` like in `dolist`, it just iterates and iteration is done for the side-effects. So it is the users task to put iteration results somewhere, if that is needed.

If it starts with `collect` or allows a `collect` clause somewhere in the body, then it should return a list of iteration results. The `loop` macro is such a construct, but one might find other iteration constructs in libraries or books.

Comment: Do note that the OP was aware that `dolist` can return a non-`nil` value after the list form;  OP's `dolist` began was `(dolist (x (table-wires inputTable) wireList) ...)`, and even seemed to be trying to build up `wireList` with `(cons x wireList)`.  Good point about `do` versus `collect`, though!